# Mapbox: Making a line given two OSM Node IDs

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, openstreetmap, mapbox-gl-js, leaflet-routing-machine

I have two `Open Street Map` node IDs. Is there any API provided by `Mapbox` or `Leaflet` which could draw a `PolyLine` or `LineString` given the two node IDs?

I am not able to find any reference to `OSM IDs` anywhere in `Mapbox` documentation, apart from [here](https://www.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/mapbox-streets-v7/#overview) and it does not detail how to use the `OSM IDs` for ourselves to draw lines on the map.

What I want to do is given 2 `OSM IDs`, I want to highlight the road segment connecting those `OSM IDs`. I can't go for things like [`Leaflet routing machine`](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine) since the number of such lines are too many, with small distances. I can't run `routing` for all the edges.

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here, have a try on http://gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: Do you want a straight line between the two OSM nodes, or a Polyline that follows the road?

Comment: @AndrewHarvey A `polyline` following the road will be much preferred

Comment: Does it need to be vehicle routing respecting oneways or just following the shortest distance paths?

Comment: @AndrewHarvey the path of the line is not very long. It's of the type of a short road segment. So there is essentially only one shortest distance. The problem is how to plot it such that it covers the width of the road exactly? In other words I am searching for a `mapbox` or `leaflet` functionality, which given two points on map, could do such a thing.

Answer (score 2):

Since you say "I can't go for things like Leaflet routing machine since the number of such lines are too many, with small distances. I can't run routing for all the edges." I'm excluding all solutions calling an external routing API, instead you can do your own internal routing.

1. Use the [OSM Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) to get the long,lat points for those nodes
2. In Mapbox GL JS fitBounds to those two nodes and do map.querySourceFeatures to get the roads as GeoJSON LineStrings
3. then compute a network graph from this and use Dijkstra's algorithm to get the shortest path between your two OSM nodes.

Comment: Thanks! Point 2 (or similar ideas) is what I am looking for. It seems this may work. I will try it and comment.

Comment: Actually if you want to work with OSM data and don't mind that it doesn't always line up with the Mapbox basemap you can use overpass instead of query source features

Comment: I really want my data to match my Mapbox basemap. I am currently using overpass API to get the node coordinates. Only problem that now remains is how to connect two nodes (which are adjacent, so no need for routing or Dijkstra) so that the connecting line has the exact width of the underlying road segment.

Comment: Do you mean the physical width of the road? Depends of if it's tagged in OSM or rendered width? In Mapbox GL you can use tte new setFeatureStates to highlight road segments directly

Comment: I mean the width displayed on `mapbox` map

Comment: Okay, so what you want to do is "How do you change the style of roads on the Mapbox base map"? Maybe best to ask that as a new question.

Comment: @AndrewHarvey how did you get lat/lng from the nodes in Overpass API? i tried searching and I can't find the way to do it, could you please be so kind and share the way to do it? Thanks a lot!